# Extract numbers from string and wrap them in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is as follows. I have this example text:

**html**

```
9216143567 is the number and other one is 0112388908
```

Now I want a JS function which finds then numbers which are together and greater than 8 in number and adds html code around them like below

`<a href="tel:9216143567" class="button button-positive">9216143567</a> is the number and other one is <a href="tel:0112388908" class="button button-positive">0112388908</a>`

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Takes string as input and gives HTML as output.

```js
var abc = 'ei32eoeiq 9216143567 is the number and other one is 0112388908, 7878787878,deewodiwqodiwp 9898903232';

var splitArray = abc.match(/\d+/g);

for(var i = 0 ; i < splitArray.length; i++){
  value = splitArray[i];
  if(value.length>8) {
    abc = abc.replace(value, '<a href="tel:'+value+'" class="button button-positive">'+value+'</a>');
   }
}
console.log(abc);
document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = abc;
```

```html
<div id="ans"></div>
```

Comment: there can be 1, 2 , 3 .. or n numbers in a string, your answer is perfect for 2 numbers, but when i added 3rd, it did not worked, see fiddle here- https://jsfiddle.net/q3v1Ltnq/1/   , please update so that it should not matter how many numbers are there

Comment: please note , text can be in the start, or in the end, dont hard code the positions , i has to find numbers>8 and wrap them anywhere in the string

Comment: Updated the answer. It wasn't hardcoded for 2 numbers. The number had ```, ``` with it which was causing issue.

Comment: instead of jquery, can we use js only ?  , if yes please update

Comment: Updated with vanilla javascript

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/DDe7TG/1): `(\d{8,})[^\d]+(\d{8,})/g`

It matches two matching groups, each of them wraps a number of at least 8 digits; where the two numbers are separated by at least one non-digit character.

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML;
let regex = /(\d{8,})[^\d]+(\d{8,})/g;
let matches = regex.exec(input);

document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "OUTPUT: The first num is " + matches[1] + " and the second is " + matches[2];
```

```html
<div id="input">
  INPUT: 9216143567 is the number and other one is 0112388908
</div><br>
<div id="ans"></div>
```

**Edit:**

If you want to extract a dynamic number of numbers, you can use a simpler regex, `\d{8,}`. I've also modified the code so it replaces the original number with a URL that directs to it.

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML;
let regex = /\d{8,}/g;
let match;
let matches_array = [];
while (match = regex.exec(input)) {
  matches_array.push(match);
}

for (let i = 0; i < matches_array.length; i++) {
  let tmp = '<a href="tel:' + matches_array[i] + '" class="button button-positive">' + matches_array[i] + '</a>';
  input = input.replace(new RegExp(matches_array[i], "g"), tmp);
}

document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = input;
```

```html
<div id="input">
  9216143567 is the number and other one is 0112388908 and the third is 1234567890
</div><br>
<div id="ans"></div>
```

Comment: why too much complicated regular expression, as well as code is also complicated

Comment: @PranayRana I assumed the OP wanted to find two numbers, each with at least 8 digits

Comment: not mentioned in his question , that is your assumption only

Comment: numbers can be any ..not just 2

Comment: @user2828442 Do you mean there can be any amount of numbers to extract?

Comment: yes, it can be 3 or 4 or5 or may be 1 , in the entire string

Comment: see fiddle here- https://jsfiddle.net/q3v1Ltnq/1/   , i made this using the code from sandeep above, his answer is also for 2 numbers but when i added 3rd his code did not work, i want it to find all numbers from string > 8 and wrap them

Comment: please note , text can be in the start, or in the end, dont hard code the positions , i has to find numbers>8 and wrap them anywhere in the string

Comment: 1 step close, we are filtering out the numbers, output needed is exactly as the input, but the numbers surrounded by the html data, see my question, for example input is -  9216142737 is my no. and landline no. is 01812231547..thank you ,

Comment: @user2828442 I think you misunderstood the purpose of Stack Overflow. This is not a free coding service. You're extremely welcome to take the code I've written and modify it to your needs, or ask for further instructions

Comment: it is perfectly ok, i knew how to filter out, but i was confused how to wrap them :)

Comment: @user2828442 After my last edit - is this what you mean?

Comment: the numbers are wrapped now but i want output text string same as input , just the difference will be , the numbers will be wrapped..hope i am able to explain